# Re-ask permissions in cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Is there a way for this cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin to re-ask permission? I'm trying to connect my app to an API that requires the user's email. In my case, if users uncheck the email in my app and continues to login Facebook, when I check the Facebook account that I used to login, it is in my apps. So is there a way to :

1. re-ask permission in Facebook login?
   or if that isn't happening
2. stop users from getting logged in Facebook if the user refuses to give his email?